# How do required select list in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to do required select list in Angular?
I tried to add param `required` in select:

```
<select name="name" ng-model="name" required>
    <option disabled>Test</option>
</select>
```

After HTML code to show error:

```
<div class="form-error" ng-show="formName.name.$invalid && !formName.name.$pristine">
You must to enter name
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the first value empty, like this:

```
<select name="name" ng-model="name" required>
    <option value="">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This also fix the problem with attribute "required" which did not work in case of ng-repeat because of element <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option> added by angular if there is no option with empty value and which work fine if there is such option, for example, in following html: <select id="type" name="type" ng-model="model.type" ng-required="model.isTypeRequired"><option value=""></option><option ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type.value}}" ng-selected="{{type.value == model.type}}">{{type.label}}</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AngularJS `ngRequired` property like so : `ng-required="true"`. You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

Comment: It gives me incorrect first option select:  `<select name="year" ng-model="year" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"><option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
<option value="0">İ</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
</select>`

Comment: I'm not entire sure what you're trying to achieve? I though you wanted to require the select to submit the form?